# share X axis and change size in the same time with subplots in python

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a dataframe as show below

```
df =
       index         value   active  
2014-05-21 10:00:00    0.0        1        
2014-05-21 11:00:00    3.4        1        
2014-05-21 12:00:00    nan        0      
2014-05-21 13:00:00    0.0        1        
2014-05-21 14:00:00    nan        0        
2014-05-21 15:00:00    1.0        1 
.....
```

and plot it by **subplots**

the code and the figure are showed below

```
f, (ax11, ax12)= plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)

ax11.plot(df.index, df.value, c='g')
ax12.scatter(df.index, df.active, s = 5)
ax12.xaxis([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2])
plt.tight_layout()
ax11.grid(True), ax12.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like to make figure *ax11* two times bigger than *ax12* and share the xaxis in the same time.

I have checked the tutorial of **subplot2grid**, **gridspec**, they both can give differents subplot size, however it seems only **subplots** could share the x- or y-axis, how can I do them both in the same time? Anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set [`gridspec_kw` in your `subplots` call](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html); otherwise, there's nothing to change.

> gridspec_kw : dict, optional
>   Dict with keywords passed to the GridSpec constructor used to create the grid the subplots are placed on.

Here's a simple example:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = subplots(2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [2, 1]})
ax1.plot([1, 2, 3]);
ax2.plot([3, 2, 4]);
```

[image]